# How to share nUnit tests in both x86 and x64 in Resharper

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I need to run some .NET unit tests in both 32-bit and 64-bit modes.

I have 2 separate test assemblies, building as x86 and x64 respectively, and nUnit successfully chooses the correct test runner.

In order to avoid duplicating the test code, I have written the tests in one project, then 'linked' the source files into the 2nd.

However, linking the source files seems to confuse the Resharper test runner. When I run an individual test in one of the projects, the single test appears to start running in *both* projects, with spurious results.

Is there a way to fix this Resharper behaviour? Or is there another way to structure the code?

(An alternative might be to author the tests in a 'common' test project built as AnyCPU, and inherit each test fixture into new classes in the specialised x86 and x64 test projects... but this seems inelegant)

Comment: It should be a CI system that run the tests in both bitness. I don't think ReSharper should be that smart.

Comment: I don't disagree... Though I'd argue this is still a bug in Resharper: the Unit Test Session dialogue is associating running tests to items in the list based on the source file it is in, rather than the project / assembly it is compiled into.

Comment: Which version of ReSharper are you using? I've seen this behaviour in previous versions of ReSharper, and I know that v9+ has changed the registration of the tests to include project name, so I suspect this is fixed in v9+

Comment: I'm using 8.2.1 - thanks, I might try an upgrade!